# how to search my own website?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to search my own website.
When I enter the key word in the search box, I want results to show on the 'searchResult.html' page.
I want the key word to be highlighted, so when I click the key word, I want to move to that page.

I searched here, but I still don't get it.
How can I make this possible?
Do I have to use php and mysql or only javascript ?
Please advise me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something fast and do not know how to do, you can use [Google Custom Search](https://cse.google.com/cse/)

Comment: I want to make my own search box instead using Google, so please advise me where to start.

Comment: @phpmyadmin2014 - If you have a database, use it with PHP to make queries on it that you return all your results on the page that you want.